# Insert class function into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have class that outputs website rank

```
$urlInfo->getUrlInfo();
```

This is the alexa amazon aws for rank. the out would be rank of domain. I need to insert the rank into the db but i can't unless i set it to a variable.

what can I do?

i have tried:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO rank (date, domain, rank) VALUES ('$date','$domain','".$urlInfo->getUrlInfo()."')")
```

but rank is empty.

this is what the geturlinfo function looks like

```
    public function getUrlInfo() {
    $queryParams = $this->buildQueryParams();
    $sig = $this->generateSignature($queryParams);
    $url = 'http://' . self::$ServiceHost . '/?' . $queryParams . 
        '&Signature=' . $sig;
    $ret = self::makeRequest($url);
    //echo "\nResults for " . $this->site .":\n\n <br>";
    self::parseResponse($ret);
}
```

the script then defines the array of the function as result

```
      public static function parseResponse($response) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response,null,false,
                                    'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
        if($xml->count() && $xml->Response->TrafficHistoryResult->Alexa->count()) {
            $info = $xml->Response->TrafficHistoryResult->Alexa;
            $nice_array = array(

//                 'City'           => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->City,
//                 'State'          => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->State,
//                 'Postal Code'    => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->PostalCode,
//                 'Country'        => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->Country,
//                 'Links In Count' => $info->ContentData->LinksInCount,
//                 'Rank'           => $info->TrafficData->Rank,
//                 'Usage'          => $info->TrafficData->UsageStatistics
                    'Rank'          => $info->TrafficHistory->HistoricalData->Data->Rank

            );
        }

                   foreach($nice_array as $k => $v) 
                    {
                        echo $k.': ' . $v ."\n <br>";
                    }

    }
```

**UPDATE:** This works. i am now able to put it in a  href=XX but still update to mysql shows blanks

```
    $accessKeyId1 = "XXX";
    $secretAccessKey1 = "XXX";
    $site1 = $_GET['domain'];
    $StartNum1 = $_GET['currentdate']; 

    //$url = $urlInfo->getUrlInfo();
    //echo "URL : ".$url;  

    function Rank($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site, $StartNum)
    {$urlInfo = new UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site, $StartNum); $urlInfo->getUrlInfo();}
    echo "test url:<a href='/";
    $test = Rank($accessKeyId1, $secretAccessKey1, $site1, $StartNum1);

    //$testing = mysql_query("UPDATE rank SET rank = '".Rank($accessKeyId1, $secretAccessKey1, $site1, $StartNum1)."' WHERE domain = '4shared.com'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $test."'>test</a>";
```

for the UPDATE i tried Rank($accessKeyId1, $secretAccessKey1, $site1, $StartNum1) and also $test.

any ideas from here?

Comment: What is your SQL query? You do not need to assign it to a variable

Comment: You might want to add details of your getUrlInfo function, as well as how you're trying to add it to the database and what the actual error is.

Comment: Does `urlInfo->getUrlInfo()` echo to the browser? If so, you'll need to modify the class function. If not, you can simply use the function as part of your query... `"INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES('" . $urlInfo->getUrlInfo() . "', 'var2' );"`

Comment: This is why some animals eat their young.

Comment: @SetSailMedia
i have tried that. but the rank column comes up empty. this is from the aws alexa example. the class just creates a outputs the results from xml of url. bigman - i dont get it.

Comment: i'd appreciate some help rather than giving me negatives. i've searched all over google and can't find any information that can tell my why it inserts into mysql as blank

Comment: can someone please help me. I've looked everywhere

Comment: try, instead of `$urlinfo->geturlinfo()` making another prepped statement above named something like `$url = $urlinfo->geturlinfo()`, then within the statement put `'$url'` and do you actually have a table called rank? because it sounds like you're calling it a column :S

Comment: now it will not allow me to put it into header("Refresh: 5, url=?currentdate=$nextDate&domain=$nextDomain&lastrank='".Rank($accessKeyId1, $secretAccessKey1, $site1, $StartNum1)."'&runtime=$nextRuntime"); <---- comes up as blank for lastrank=

Comment: can you describe (by editing your question) what exactly you can do and what you want to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, instead of `$urlinfo->geturlinfo()` making another prepped statement above named something like `$url = $urlinfo->geturlinfo()`,then within the statement put `'$url'` so:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rank (date, domain, rank) VALUES ('$date','$domain','$url')");
```

i think the main problem you are having is the quotation marks, it is splitting the statement into two parts which means the statement isn't complete (don't quote me on that)

finally do you actually have a table called rank? because it sounds like you're calling it a column/ row.

I'm only working through my own thought process, I hope this works/ helps =]

---

in the comments i was saying that you should do is this->

```
$rank = $this->url->getNewValue();
$url = $this->$rank->getUrlInfo();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO rank (date, domain, rank) VALUES ('$date','$domain','$url')");
```

---

Although i would have a look at the link below about `SQL Injection` it will help protect your application from Hackers.

[SQL Injection: Information](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/sql-injection-information) 
[SQL Injection: Prevention](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/sql-injection-prevention)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried just about about everything. i have defined it like you said and still it outputs blank. the only time it outputs the rank is when i use $urlinfo->geturlinfo(). I have tried $urlinfo->nice_array and $urlinfo->parseResponse I just dont understand why it wont let me store the data. i can't even put it in a url so <a href=/'"$urlinfo->getUrlInfo()."'>Rank</a> does not work either.

Comment: could you try with the input box, say its named `"url"` try this; `$rank = url->getNewValue();` then `$url = $rank->geturlinfo()` then try in the statement `$url` again I'm trying to note down my thought process so i'm not sure if its correct. what is the column type that you are using?

Comment: should i create a function in the class called getNewValue? so create a functions getNewValue(){$url = $UrlInfo->getUrlInfo();} then call that?

Comment: thanks for the help! i get to atleast go into a URL now. please see my update.